# JDBC - MultiDimensional Array and Parsing Results

Tags: arrays, string, parsing, jdbc, multidimensional-array

Before exposing my question I have to say that I'd never had a java or even development studies. So sorry If my question seems "stupid"...

I have to dispay results into a Panel from several columns from a derby database.

In order to do that i have a method which returns me an array for a column and a Resultset:

```
public String[] toStringArray(ResultSet resultSet, int columnIndex) {
    LinkedList<String> resultList = new LinkedList<String>();
    try {
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            resultList.add(resultSet.getString(columnIndex));
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return resultList.toArray(new String[0]);
}
```

Here is my second methoid which returns a two dimensional array throught the first method from the first and second column of my database...

```
public String[][] GetArray() {
String[] arrayone = new String[0];
String[] arraytwo = new String[1];
String[][] array = new String[2][];

try {
    String getInfo =
                     "SELECT ONE, TWO FROM APP.DB ";

ResultSet listR = s.executeQuery(getInfo);
arrayone = toStringArray(listR,1);
arraytwo = toStringArray(listR,2);
   array [0] = arrayone; 
   array [1] = arraytwo; 

} } }catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(CalendarPanelTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }}
      return array;

}
```

So I return a two array dimension with the result of two columns from the database...

Now I display It like that (with the idea that the number of results are the same from the two columns result query - or null values have to be feeded for display):

```
String[][] result = GetArray();

int nb = array.length;
for(int a=0; a < nb; a++) 
{
System.print.ln(result[0][a]+result[1][a])
}
```

I think the problem is in the

```
return resultList.toArray(new String[0]);
```

I tried to change this object with no result...

Which seems to push datas only into the first column...

Or form my method or in the delacartion of the colums array:

```
String[] arrayone = new String[0];
String[] arraytwo = new String[1];
String[][] array = new String[2][];
```

But I tried all number possibilities and this one give me the result from the first colum when I want to display it... :

```
String[][] array = new String[2][];
```

even if

```
String[][] array = new String[1][]
```

or

```
String[][] array = new String[0][1];
```

seems more logical...

I'll be very pleased to have some proposal of solution to construct correctly this two dimensionnal array or to give me the way to another better solution...

Is an array the best way to do that ? If I need to display the results of 10 colmuns which could be the best/quick way to achieve that ?

Best Regards, And Sorry for my poor english...

EDIT: My solution was to add a second resultset for the second value:

```
ResultSet listR = s.executeQuery(getInfo);
    ResultSet listR2 = s.executeQuery(getInfo);
    arrayone = toStringArray(listR,1);
    arraytwo = toStringArray(listR2,2);
```

Thanks to Soumyadip Das for his help !!! Regards,

Working speed Is working right at the first time...

Answer (score 1):

I think **you missed the closing bracket** as follows:

```
public String[] toStringArray(ResultSet resultSet, int columnIndex) {
    LinkedList<String> resultList = new LinkedList<String>();
    try {
        while (resultSet.next()) { // where is the closing bracket ??
            resultList.add(resultSet.getString(columnIndex));
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return resultList.toArray(new String[0]);
}
```

If this just a posting mistake then check as below:

---

I think make it simple, may be I am wrong, but you may try this:

```
public String[] toStringArray(ResultSet resultSet, int columnIndex) {
    ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
    // COMMENT: please debug your code to be sure the resultSet is not empty.
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            results.add(resultSet.getString(columnIndex));}
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return results.toArray();
}
```

The following 2 lines may cause problem:

```
 array [0] = arrayone; 
   array [1] = arraytwo;
```

**SUGGESTION:** always properly debug your code.. it may solve 80% of your problems.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sorry for the brackets, there was some "println" code that I remove with the "while end" bracket. I tried your solution but yes array [1] = arraytwo; and array [0] = arrayone;  cause problem, I don't know how to get back the data... I'm going to search forward and I'll post again if I find a working issue. WHat do you say about "debug your code", you say "pay attention" or "use some tools like Junit ?" I am a network and system administrator and poorly I code like I script...

Comment: Finnaly the code above is working but I had to add a second resultset for the second value...ResultSet listR = s.executeQuery(getInfo);ResultSet listR2 = s.executeQuery(getInfo);
arrayone = toStringArray(listR,1);
arraytwo = toStringArray(listR2,2); BUt you'are right debug my code is the first thing to do !!! Regards,

Comment: Good to know that it helped you... all the best. Please accpet the answer & upvote it!! :)